# bounded area enclosed by $f(x)$ and its inverse and tangents and normal

Tags: calculus

Area bounded by $y=f^{-1}(x)$ and tangent and normal drawn to it the points with

abscissa $\pi$ and $2\pi.$ where $f(x)= x-\sin x$

Attempt: $f(x)= x-\sin x$ is strictly increasing function but i could notunderstand how to

calculate $f^{-1}(x)$ and draw tangents and normal at $P(\pi,)$ and $Q(2\pi,)$

could some help me , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sketch of the reflection of the region in the line $y=x$.

The region you seek has the same area as this region using the graph of $f$.

The tangent lines at points $(\pi,\pi)$ and $(2\pi,2\pi)$ are

$$ y=2x-\pi \text{ and } y=2\pi $$

The area is the sum of two integrals which break at $x=\dfrac{3\pi}{2}$ and is elementary.

You should find that the area is $A=\dfrac{\pi^2}{4}-2$.
[image: sketch of region]

The normal line at $(2\pi,2\pi)$ on the graph of $f$ is vertical. The normal line at $(\pi,\pi)$ has slope $-\frac{1}{2}$ since it is perpendicular to the tangent line.

For the region bounded by the normals and the graph of $f(x)$ one must solve the integral

$$ \int_\pi^{2\pi}x-\sin x-\left(-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)\,dx $$

I computed a value of $2+\frac{15\pi^2}{4}$ but this should be double-checked. Here is a graph of the region.

[image: Bounded region]

Comment: How did you got the ordinates and normals?

Comment: @AnuranChowdhury I only worked the case of the tangent lines, not the normal lines. And rather than using $f^{-1}$ which I believe was intended to needlessly complicate the exercise, I used the graph of $f(x)=x-\sin(x)$ which is merely the graph of $f^{-1}$ reflected about the graph of $y=x$, so the areas of the regions are the same. I will add the case of the normal lines to the exercise.

Comment: Thanks for answering! On a different note, did you use softwares for the graphs or you draw it in pen and paper first? I'm asking this because I want to know how to draw graph of x-sinx from the graph of y=-x and y=sinx itself

Comment: @AnuranChowdhury  I used the excellent online graphing site https://desmos.com/calculator/ Below is a link to a graph of this particular problem showing both regions in one graph. If you look at the equations on the left of the graph you can see how I plotted the graphs and shaded the regions. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4gxxl93rrw

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** With $P:\,y(\pi)=\pi$ and tangant line equation $y-\pi=m(x-\pi)$ use $$m=(f^{-1})'(y)=\dfrac{1}{f'(x)}=\dfrac{1}{f'(\pi)}$$