# Area bounded by inverse image of a curve, its tangents and normals

Tags: definite-integrals, area

Determine the area bounded by $$y=f^{^{-1}}(x)$$ and tangent and normal drawn to it at the points with abscissa $$\pi$$ and $$2\pi$$ where $$f(x)=\sin x-x$$

I tried to find the inverse image of $\sin x-x$ and got stuck with $x=\sin y-y$, which isn't going anyway so does this standard method of finding inverse of a function works in case of Trigonometric expression like this?

Comment: any thoughts by yourself?

Comment: Edited within the question.

Comment: @AnuranChowdhury You don't need to find the inverse. See my answer.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2247531/bounded-area-enclosed-by-fx-and-its-inverse-and-tangents-and-normal

Comment: My question is sinx-x, not x-sinx

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Suppose we have some function $f$ and we want to calculate
$$\int_a^b f^{-1}(x)dx$$
with the assumption that $f$ is injective on $[a,b]$. Then let us make the substitution $x \to f(y)$ and $dx\to f'(y)dy$ so that we then have
$$\int_{f^{-1}(a)}^{f^{-1}(b)} yf'(y)dy$$
and so we have the identity
$$\int_a^b f^{-1}(x)dx=\int_{f^{-1}(a)}^{f^{-1}(b)} yf'(y)dy$$
Can you use this to solve your problem?

If anything is unclear, just ask, and I will be happy to explain.

Comment: That's brilliant! One question, how did you get the limits? By putting x=a? Since x=f(y)=>a=f(y)=y=f^-1(a)?

Comment: @AnuranChowdhury As a general rule of substitution with definite integrals,
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_{g^{-1}(a)}^{g^{-1}(b)}g'(x)f(g(x))dx$$
That's just a general property of definite integrals.

And thanks! If you found it helpful, don't forget to $\checkmark$! :D

Comment: Also, how to find tangents and normals of the inverse of this function without knowing the function? As we have to find the area enclosed withing the graph, it's tangent and it's normal.

Comment: @AnuranChowdhury Note that the graph of the inverse of a function $y=f(x)$ is the reflection of $y=f^{-1}(x)$ reflected about the line $y=x$. Thus, to find the tangent to $y=f^{-1}(x)$ at $x=a$, just find the tangent to $y=f(x)$ at $x=f^{-1}(a)$ and reflect it about $y=x$!

Comment: Thanks a lot for making concepts clear :)

Comment: @AnuranChowdhury No problem, glad I could help! If you need anything else cleared up, just ask! :)

Comment: The final answer I'm getting is π²/2-2. Could you please check it?

Comment: Hm, yes. Give me a moment.

Comment: @AnuranChowdhury The question is a bit unclear - am I finding the area bounded by the tangents and normals, or by the curve and its tangents?

Comment: Area between the curve, it's tangent and it's normal.

Comment: @AnuranChowdhury Look at the second graph that I posted in my answer. Should it look like that?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztFj5.png

Comment: @AnuranChowdhury That's just a tangent and a tangent. But okay, that makes it easier! :D

Comment: @AnuranChowdhury Yeah, I think you're correct. If you show your work in your question, it will help me verify it though.

Comment: Found the graph elsewhere, not in the question itself. Wolfram gave me the graph of sinx-x which I reflected on the line y=x.

Comment: @AnuranChowdhury Your answer looks correct to me. Don't take my word for it though, b/c my check was kind of rushed. :P

Answer (score 1):

Given $y=f^{-1}(x)$, you have $x=f(y)=\sin y-y$, that can be represented as
\begin{align}
x &= \sin t-t \\
y &= t
\end{align}
Next, $x=\pi$ implies $\sin t -t = \pi$, from which $t=-\pi$, then
\begin{align}
x' &= \cos t-1 \\
y' &= 1
\end{align}
and substitute $t=-\pi$.